# disabling sms content and just seeing name on the lockscreen

Tags: sms

I have an htc one. Is there a way to disable the sms content in lockscreen and just see the name, without using any other application?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an HTC One, but I use Go SMS Pro which is a third party SMS/MMS app that has a easy setting in there to only show a "New Message" notification instead of actually showing the message's contents. You said you didn't want another application, so you might be able to look through the settings of the default messaging app on the One and see if there is something similar.

If not, I highly recommend [Go SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) to solve this issue and several others.